# Implementation of B+ tree

Tags: implementation

I am trying to implement a B+ tree. So far I have  leaf node, root node, inner node classes. Inside my lead node class, I have a list for keys and a list for values. My question is that instead of having  lists for values and keys, Can I have a map pairing key to value? If no, can you explain why.

Comment: A map implemented with a B+Tree?

Comment: I am trying to implement search. Once I find the matching key, I want to return the value. How do i do that? Can I have a map stored in the node class that will map the key to the value? Or I need an Array List of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would build a B+Tree from lower-level data structures.

A map is normally implemented as a Tree itself, so if you already have maps why are you implementing a B+Tree?

Even using a list is a bad fit... a B+ page should be implemented using only arrays (or even better raw bytes in which you allocate arrays).

Comment: Normally in a B+ middle page you have `n` keys and `n+1` pointers to other pages, in a leaf page you have `n` keys and `n` values.

Comment: Managing the array in the B+-Tree page with the gap-buffer technique (look it up) is an excellent optimization you may want to implement if you expect to do many sequential insertions.